# Can anyone tell me why this works in eclipse but not in the command prompt?

Tags: java, eclipse, command, prompt, symbols

I have 3 classes that I got from my lecturer as an assignment and before I edit them at all I tried to compile them. They won't compile in the command prompt citing a "**`cannot find symbol error`**" in reference to "`DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();`". I then tried running it in Eclipse and it works perfectly, any ideas on why or even how I can get it to work in my command prompt

**TestDraw.java:**

```
    package shapessimple;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    public class TestDraw
     {
        public static void main (String[]args)
     {
            DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
            JFrame application = new JFrame();

            application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            application.add(panel);
            application.setSize(300,300);
            application.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

---

**DrawPanel.java:**

```
package shapessimple;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private Random randomNumbers = new Random();
    private MyLine[] lines;


    public DrawPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.white);

        lines = new MyLine[5 + randomNumbers.nextInt(5)];

        for (int count = 0; count < lines.length; count++) {
            int x1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
            int x2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
            int y1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);
            int y2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(300);

            Color color = new Color(randomNumbers.nextInt(256),
                    randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256));

            lines[count] = new MyLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
        } 
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (MyLine line : lines) {
            line.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**MyLine.java:**

```
package shapessimple;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MyLine {
    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;
    private Color myColor;

    public MyLine (int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        myColor = color;
    }

    public void draw (Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(myColor);
        g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,x2);
    }
}
```

### **EDIT:**

It's compiling now, but I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError: TestDraw error message`

Comment: What is the full command you used to try to run it?

Comment: @StephenHogarty That's for **compiling**. glad3dr asked you the command you use to **run**.

Comment: why not `javac *.java`?

Comment: it wouldn't compile in the command prompt. in eclipse I pressed run

Comment: @StephenHogarty You have to include _all_ of the files in the command to compile it: `javac TestDraw.java DrawPanel.java MyLine.java`

Comment: @Dici He seems to be confused about the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

In order to run the application you need to compile all .java files that you use instead of compiling only 'TestDraw.java'. Make sure that you have a .class file for every source .java file and that they're all in the sharpesimple folder.

Then to run the app just do `java shapesimple.TestDraw` and it should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To have to compile all of the files before you can run the program from command line. To compile it you have to include all of the files:

`javac TestDraw.java DrawPanel.java MyLine.java`

or you could just do

`javac *.java`

Then you should be able to run the program by running the file with `main()` in it, and specifying the classpath so that the class loader knows where to look:

`java -cp . TestDraw`

If you do not set the class path, then the class loader will just use the value of the CLASSPATH environment variable, which likely does not contain the directory contianing your program.

Note that when running a `.class` file, you do **not** include the .class extension.

Comment: Thanks now it compiles fine, but it won't run. Now I'm getting a NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Can you post an edit to the question with the full error?

Comment: @StephenHogarty Try running it from the parent directory with `java shapesimple.TestDraw` like @MikeLaren suggested.

Comment: when I do that it say **Error: Could not find or load main class shapessimple.TestDraw**

Comment: @StephenHogarty I've edited the part about running the program in my answer. Try that.

Comment: nope still getting the error

Comment: The method I put here should be done from inside the same directory as the files. Did you do that?

Comment: what method? And yes all the files are in the same folder, I'm not a complete idiot

Comment: I know they are all in the same directory. That's not what I asked. I asked if you are running the command from inside the same directory as the files.

Comment: yeah im in the same directory as the files.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the parent Folder of `shapessimple` and try the following command if you are running on a Windows machien:

```
javac -cp ./:%CLASSPATH% shapessimple.TestDraw.java
```

or on a Linux machine:

```
javac -cp ./;$CLASSPATH shapessimple.TestDraw.java
```

Comment: The OP needs to compile all his classes before running it. You are compiling 1 class file. It won't find the rest of the class files as they are not compiled.